# Run auto slidepage android using timer

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Now I find some solution to auto run image on viewpager but I don't know how we make it.

I read many post about timer, runnable and handle. Who can guess some solution?

Github link for my code is below,
https://github.com/QuangTo/DemoSimple/blob/qtv/app/src/main/java/com/example/qtv/myapplication/view/ThreeFragment.java.

Comment: You should use Viewpager for this functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this using Timer task and OnPageChangeListener to get which is the current page selected. If their is any better solution [update me too!].
Its working fine for me.

You can use TimerTask for that.

Check out this code:

```
    /*Iterate the view pager after certain interval*/

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    int nextPage = 0;
    int noOfBanners;
    RemindTask(int noOfBanners) {
        this.noOfBanners = noOfBanners;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                calledByTimer = true;
                page = listener.getCurrentPage();
                nextPage = page + 1;
                if (firstTime) {
                    nextPage = page;
                    firstTime = false;
                }
                if (page > noOfBanners) timer.cancel();
                else if (page == imageUrls.length - 1) pager.setCurrentItem(0);
                else pager.setCurrentItem(nextPage);
            }
        });
    }
}


   public void pageSwitcher(int seconds, int length) {
    swipeAtInterval = new RemindTask(length);
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(swipeAtInterval, 0, seconds * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Hi Shubham. thanks for review it. but u can explain something in method for me. ex : page = listener.getCurrentPage(); and some value in class. im noob :D. so have isuue i not understand.